# "I obfuscated our conversation with loud music to avoid recording."

Tags: word-usage

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/409364/217285) to the question [Camouflage is to sight as ____ is to sound?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/409312/217285) includes the sentence:

"**I [obfuscated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obfuscation) our conversation with loud music to avoid recording**."

The linked definition says:

> The action of making something obscure, unclear, or unintelligible.
>   ‘*when confronted with sharp questions they resort to obfuscation*’
>   [count noun] ‘*ministers put up mealy-mouthed denials and obfuscations*’
>
> Origin: Late Middle English: from late Latin obfuscatio(n-), from obfuscare ‘to darken or obscure’ (see obfuscate).

The most up voted answer there (and the one I like) is **mask**. When I think of obfuscate, I think of manipulating information to confuse or misdirect someone's interpretation of a situation or a communication, so I was surprised to see this use.

Yes, sound is information in some sense, but the information we extract from the sound of speech is not the same as the initial waveforms and vibrations in the air.

Can one *obfuscate a conversation* by masking it acoustically? Is this a proper use of *obfuscate*, or is it a bit of a stretch?

Comment: You can **mask** a conversation with some kind of other sound.

Comment: @GlobalCharm I'm not sure of your point; I've addressed masking in the question already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**That's not how I would use *obfuscate*.**

I think you can make (especially in reference to spoken communication) a distinction between making a conversation difficult to *understand* and making it difficult to *discern*.

Obfuscation could involve using slang, overly convoluted language, code words, phonological transformations such as pig Latin, etc. These are all things that would make it hard for an eavesdropper who can clearly discern the sounds made in the conversation to understand what was actually being communication.

Playing loud music (or whispering, or replacing some or all of the spoken words with gestures or written notes) makes the conversation harder to discern, and that isn't *obfuscation* as I understand the word.

Imagine if there was a written transcript of the conversation. If the transcript is complete and accurate and the conversation is still hard to understand, it may have been deliberately obfuscated by the conversationalists. Playing loud music just makes it harder to get the complete and accurate transcript.

Comment: I would argue that making something difficult to discern, by definition, makes it difficult to understand, and so obfuscation includes both things. While I would agree that obfuscation is both less common a term and less precise in this situation, making it unusual, I don't think it's wrong, just less suitable. I can imagine situations where it becomes more suitable thanks to *intent* - if the context is someone trying to mislead, "obfuscate" might be more suitable, as it might hint at a different purpose than "masking".

Comment: Of course Marq is correct.  Obfuscation (of _written_ or _audio_) language means obfuscating the platonic words.  On the other hand, when you distort literally the audio track or blur the image, you refer to that as blurring, pixelating, masking, "covering with white noise", etc.  (Note that there happens to be no common word for "covering with white noise", other than industry technical terms, but so what? A zillion verb-phrases in English, particularly modern technical concepts, have no one-word-version - nothing to see here, a non-issue.)

Answer (score 8):

by using an acoustic mask (loud music) you *obfuscated* the conversation and made the conversation unclear (to eavesdroppers).

**yes**, it's proper use of the word obfuscate and **no**, it's not a bit of stretch.

you can check out  [obfuscate in a sentence](http://sentencedict.com/obfuscate.html).

Comment: Please add some support for your answer, for example a quote. See an example of obfuscate used 'in real life': http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6853696/?reload=true

Comment: The ieee abstract only covers the speaker identity obfuscation.

Comment: @chornge interesting answer! There is a distinction between an audio recording of speech being unclear, and the meaning of the speech being unclear. Are you sure both usages of "unclear" are correct here?

Comment: @Stefan I'm going to go look that up and read it, and then look for more! Thanks for the link.

Comment: @uhoh i meant the the audio recording of the speech being unclear and not the meaning of the speech (unless it was spoken in another language which would add another layer of obfuscation).

Comment: OK I see. My thinking is that it is meaning, thoughts, ideas, interpretations etc. can be obfuscated, not the primary audio recording of sound. I've looked at the examples in your link and they all seem to relate to the obfuscation of meaning etc.

Comment: yes, you're correct - when trying to listen to the conversation, the loud music masks the words being spoken thereby making it unclear what is being said. on a related note, you can obfuscate an audio recording but you would most likely need a software or some specialized tool to scramble the words.

Comment: I think one of the [examples](https://wordsinasentence.com/obfuscate-in-a-sentence/) is not correct though; "Because I am a sympathetic teacher, I avoid using language which will obfuscate my students." Shouldn't it be "obfuscate my lesson"? Can one easily obfuscate an entire student?

Comment: @uhoh Many of those examples aren't correct usage. They seem to be treating _obfuscate_ as a synonym for _confuse_, which it isn't.

Comment: i have posted a better link

Comment: Might be technically OK, but I'd still put a big red underlined AWK above it in text. There's no need to throw a big word like obfuscate in there to get the correct meaning across.

Answer (score 1):

If "conversation isn't information" then it's no wonder this puzzles you.
Anything molested from intended outcome can be said to have been obfuscated.
"scientists" obfuscate data to arrive at a desired outcome.
Lawyers obfuscate the truth to arrive at a molded conclusion.
Politicians obfuscate the facts to manipulate opinions.
Obfuscation is arguably the pass time of humanity, for with one lie, misdirection of truth, application of personal will, the altruist intent is obfuscated.

Comment: Who said conversation isn't information?